# NullPointerException LayoutInflater.from(context) - Fragment Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, android-nested-fragment

I have implement Nested Fragments. Child fragment contains BaseAdapter. When I switching(replace) child fragments then I am getting Nullpointer exception. 
Code:

```
public MyAdapter(final Context context,
            final List<CusomObject> CusomObjectList) {
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.CusomObjectList = CusomObjectList;     
    }
```

I am getting error in this line - `mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);`

I passed `getActivity()` in `MyAdapter` constructor from Fragment.

Code:

```
adapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity(), customList);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: try after changing `final Context context` to `final Activity activity` and use `mInflater=activity.getLayoutInflater()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I passed getActivity() in MyAdapter constructor from Fragment.

that's extactly the problem.

when `Fragment` constructor is called - the reference to the `Activity` is still not initiated.

instead - you should do any object creations or initializations that depends on `Activity` context from the Fragment's `onCreate()` method.

in general, it's not recommended at all to override `Fragment` constructor, exactly like that you don't override `Activity` constructor, but only it life-cycle callbacks.

more info in - http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: Thanks, Your answer solved my problem. So I accepted your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use another variable.

```
Context mContext;

public MyAdapter(final Context context,
        final List<CusomObject> CusomObjectList) {
    this.mContext = context;
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    this.CusomObjectList = CusomObjectList;     
}
```